# Why does float "adds" a new line to the element?

Tags: css

The point is to have a single line on this menu, wrapped. 
Instead, we are getting "two lines" and I'm not getting why is he dropping the line.

Can anyone please drop me a quick look about how is this happening ?

The HTML

```
<div id="main-menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main-menu {
    clear: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 75px;
    float:right;
}

#main-menu ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
}

#main-menu ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 2px 2%;
}

#main-menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .9em;
}

#main-menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #EFAB00;
}

#main-menu ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/XRm6Q/2/

Comment: This is weird: if I open that jsfiddle in chrome, go to 'inspect element' and click on the div with id `main-menu` it transforms into a single line?! :D

Comment: Why don't you set the width of `#main-menu ul` like 150px..  http://jsfiddle.net/XRm6Q/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't caused by the `float`, it's because of the padding you're applying to your `li`s (because when you have percentage `padding`s, the parent doesn't resize-to-fit). If you change your `padding: 2px 2%;` to `padding: 2px;` the wrapping will be gone: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/XRm6Q/11/).

Hope that helped!

Comment: @Adoby97: I wish to give a % padding there, for build it elastic. But that information "when you have percentage paddings the parent doesn't resize-to-fit" - can you please sustain it with some sort of relevant link please ? (I really wish to understand).

Comment: Well, it's a matter of logic. If the parent resizes to fit the new percentage padding, then the percentage's value will change. So take your case, we want the parent to resize to fit the `2%` padding. But after it resizes, the value of `2%` will change. This could go on forever that way.

Comment: I'm not totally get it. Don't take me wrong, I'm strugling to get this logic understood. ;) So, if that is the case, shouldn't it narrow and narrow and narrow, dropping all items to their single line? Instead however, it seems that we get an arbitrary width defined... :s

Comment: It's not arbitrary. My point is: the parent's width is fixed before applying the percentage `padding`s. So first it ignores the padding, calculates the appropriate width, then applies the padding. The issue here is that since it calculated the width without padding in consideration, when padding is applied it causes overflow and thus "wrap".

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Adoby97 - Isn't there a way to make it work by preserving the % ?

Comment: @MEM You could just prevent wrapping completely like @F.Calderan suggested, or define an explicit width. Unfortunately there's no way to keep it "normal" while preserving the percentage-`padding`s.

Comment: @Adoby97 - if I define a specific width to the parent you will notice that the background color will not properly fit as intended. The best I was able to achieve was to use your first suggestion, with nowrap declarations, nor width defined on the parent, and just use em, and completely drop the % :/

Answer (score 1):

It's because the parent element (ul) is simply not wide enough to accommodate your lis.

Make the UL wider and it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/XRm6Q/8/

---

Add `width: 100%;` to the parent DIV, not the UL. Sorry :D

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/XRm6Q/16/

Comment: I have not defined any width to the UL so I was expecting it to be 100% of the container. Is this a wrong assumption ?

Comment: It should be, but you might need to set it to width: 100%;

Comment: The reason why a child element just gets wides as is parent, only if, the parent as a width set, it's something I'm struggling to understand. For now, however, I'm happy that you recall me that.

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/XRm6Q/10/

I used `white-space: nowrap;` on `ul` element and `white space: normal` on `li` elements. In this way you don't need to adjust the parent width *(then just remove/adjust the extra padding on `li` elements or use a margin instead)*

Doing so, all the items will stay in the same row

Comment: I like your approach. I've been told however that, every time we have something with a float, it really is a good idea to also have a width declared to avoid unpredictable behaviors on some browsers. I've my self found some of this issues. So, your suggestion works. But, if I add a specific width, then the "wrap effect" it's gone. Do you agree this may be an issue ?

Comment: yes but maybe you could use a `max/min-width` instead of `width`

Comment: If we add more items to the li, it doesn't seem to work properly. Regardless if I use padding or margin. So, no luck. :( http://jsfiddle.net/XRm6Q/21/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XRm6Q/23/ it seems it works as expected. The problem with your code is the `2%` padding of an undefined parent width (or 100% width). Define a width in px or em instead

Comment: Your last code is not the intended result. If you look here: http://jsfiddle.net/XRm6Q/44/ you will notice that the background color on hover is properly wrapping more then just the li (or the li is wider here). So, I guess, for this to properly work, we can't use %, and we will have no need to white-space: nowrap and just, as you and Adoby97 have suggested: not use % for paddings here, and use em instead.

Answer (score 1):

Either set a `width` on the menu, or use `table-row` `display` for it, and `table-cell` for the items. In the latter case you'll probably what `white-space: nowrap` on the items too, but it has advantages if you don't know what the width will be.

Comment: change the display to table-row seems to not be good supported cross browser land (last time I checked). A similar suggestion as been offered by F. Calderan without the need of table-row display property.

Comment: Yes. `table-cell` (you can actually skip the row in this case as there is only one row) support is improving, but F. Calderan's approach looks better. Setting width is best of all with any float, but that's not always easy to predict with varying content.